# How to undo a ROLLBACK in sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, transactions

I am learning Oracle SQL, and after a `DELETE` command I tried to do a `ROLLBACK`. The problem is that I pressed by mistake F9 a second time and the `ROLLBACK` ran once again. Now it has deleted all my `INSERT`s from the table and I don't know how can I get them back.

I tried to insert again the same queries, but there was a problem with the `PK` (primary key). Also, I can't delete the table to start all over again because I have other tables using `FK` (foreign keys) in conjunction with this one.

Comment: Try to use Oracle flashback: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_flashback.htm#g1025568

Comment: @PetroK AFAIK you can't flashback uncommitted changes.

Comment: If the re-run inserts are failing with PK errors (it would be better to include the actual statements and errors) then rows with those key values already exist; so why do you think the previous inserts were rolled back too?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you cannot undo a `ROLLBACK`, just like you cannot undo a `COMMIT`. This is by design.

What happens when you do `ROLLBACK` is that all un-commited changes until that point are lost. Calling `ROLLBACK` twice has no effect if you do not perform any changes between the two invocations.

So the question is : did you `COMMIT` your `INSERT`s before running your `DELETE` ?

- if yes :  the `ROLLBACK` just reverted the `DELETE` command, your `INSERT`s should not be lost
- if no : the `ROLLBACK` reverted also the `INSERT`s

In both scenarios it does not matter whether your called `ROLLBACK` once or twice.

Answer (score 0):

You can't undo a rollback.  Rollback **isn't** an "undo" so it has no "redo".  It's "throw these changes away, I don't want them"

I would suggest you start a second question where you explain what you meant by:  *"there was a problem with the PK (primary key)."* and ask for help with that.

There's no way back, the only way is forward.